# Swapping Joomla Over To Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, joomla

I'm currently attempting to swap a client's website over from Joomla to WordPress and I'm having some difficulties. When I install WordPress, everything works fine except it becomes a second website.

The Joomla website (i.e. the original website and URL) stays the same but the URL with the /wp-admin appended becomes a separate website. I need to replace all Joomla files on the original website with WordPress files without creating a second website.

I've tried removing all files in the public_html directory entirely and replacing them with WordPress files but nothing works, I just end up with a broken website with a URL structure of www.example.com.au/wp-admin/wp-admin

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. Yes I have tried the Joomla to WordPress plugin and it did not work.

Comment: Are you trying to preserve and migrate the data? From your description it is unclear.  If so you need to build the site somewhere else and then when it's done you can migrate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is altogether different file structure, global variables, libraries in both CMS. It can't work just by placing all Joomla files into Wordpress. All you should do is understand the data present in your Joomla site(like articles, menus, etc) and move that data into Wordpress. By placing Joomla files in Wordpress, you are attempting to get Wordpress data in Joomla's way. That can't be done.